# Highcharts Solid Gauge width?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obn7ddLp/), I try to make the 'width' thinner, but failed by changing the value of `background.innerRadius` & `background.outerRadius`. I do understand that the two values mean to change the style of **background** but which property should I change to adjust the width of the colored loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the appropriate innerRadius to the plotOptions.solidgauge Object:

```
plotOptions: {
  solidgauge: {
    innerRadius: '80%',
    dataLabels: {
     [...]
    }
  }
}
```